# Working with Threads (start & stop them)

Tags: java, concurrency, swt

I have two SWT buttons - "Start" and "Stop" and an `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List`.
In the list I keep a directory and a printer name.

The idea is to send files (PDFs) in a specified directory to a specified printer (`print(inputPath, printerName)`).

So, when I click on "Start", a new `Thread()` is created in order to call the `print(inputPath, printerName)`.

Basically, the task is:

Every time "Start" is clicked - a new Thread is created (every time the `list.getItem(list.getSelectionIndices())` is different).

Every time "Stop" is clicked - destroy the particular Thread (for the same `list.getItem(list.getSelectionIndices())`).

I saw a few example with `Future`, `ExecutorService`, `Runnable`, etc, but I can't figure out how to combine it all together so that it will solve my problem.

So, any help/hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Just have a Thread class variable.  When you click the button start, check to see if a thread already exists, if it doesnt then create the new thread and start it.  The `isRunning()` just checks a `boolean` to see if the thread is in a running state

```
if (thread == null || !thread.isRunning()){
    thread = new MyThreadClass();
    thread.start();
}
```

When you click stop, set a flag in the thread that will tell it it's now done processing, something like `setStop()`.

```
if (thread != null){
    thread.setStop();
}
```